# How to enable android to delete cache on SDcard?

Tags: android, caching, sd-card

What must I do that Android can delete my cache files on the sdcard with the GUI?

I saved some data in `/sdcard/Android/data/my.package.name/cache` but Android tells me that my app has 0B cached data. That is wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never hardwire paths -- for example, your path shown above is incorrect for most Android devices, as `/sdcard` is not where external storage resides. You should be using `getExternalCacheDir()` for external cache and `getCacheDir()` for internal cache.

Bear in mind, as the documentation states:

> There is no guarantee when these files will be deleted. **Note: you should not rely on the system deleting these files for you; you should always have a reasonable maximum, such as 1 MB, for the amount of space you consume with cache files, and prune those files when exceeding that space.**

(emphasis theirs)

Comment: I use in real this code to build the path: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/"+packageName+"/cache/"+fileName`. But shoudn't it be possible to delete the cache with the GUI?

Comment: @rekire: First, if you are not using `getExternalCacheDir()`, the OS may not know that your particular directory is a cache. For example, if you are running this on an older Android, before `getExternalCacheDir()` was added, Android will have no concept of external cache at all. All that being said, I have no idea what drives that button in the Settings app -- for all I know, it might only address internal storage, not external.

Comment: good point I should use `getExternalCacheDir()`. I think so too that the Settings app only address the internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find valid source of this but after multiple tests I am most certain that external storage does not show up under this "clear cache" button.

It's on you to clear cache manually